# my wireless signal got ether weakend or no loger working after using Software updater on Ubuntu 13.10 how to fix this

Tags: 13.10

I am new to both linux and ubuntu And giving them a try . after installing ubuntu 13.10. the wireless seems to work just fine. Then the "software updater" showed that there is some updates. and so i click install and left it doing its thing.

Came back to it saying that i need to be connected to the internet (strange i though i was already connected to the internet) looked at the top the screen and see the wireless icon show an empty pie. so i click on it and my home network is no longer there. found it under "connect to hidden wi-fi network" and try to connect to them, but to no advail.

Went to System setting > Network. and it says it "out of range". (how could i be out of range when i am within arm reach of the router). so far having it tethered to my tablet is the only way i can get internet access to it (haven't tried plugging an ethernet cable into my computer though, so i don't know if that been effected or not)

Is there a way to fix this, can reinstall ubuntu 13.10 (and not click on "software updater) fix my issue? if yes, how and will it missed up the current one that is already installed and updated a bit. (beside reordering the boot order in the bios).

i also got ndiswrapper, but so far i can't even find it even to i have installed it from the software center.

If it helps my computer that contains Ubuntu 13.10 is Gigabyte BG-BXPi3-4010

wireless card is Realtek RTL8723AE

Please and Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is since it was working before you updated the ndiswrapper, you might need to update your kernel to work with the new version

So first do:

apt-cache search linux-image

then do:

sudo apt-get install linux-image-your_version_choice

Comment: I was about to do that, after reading your answer today. and I turn the computer on and somehow it fix itself and its working fine just as it did before i did "software updater" & put "ndiswrapper" on (and still working fine after "software updater" says that there is more). still don't know why it stop before and why is it working 100% fine now, anyways Thanks for the help